# fd in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I was reading up on some pickle vulnerabilities and found this piece of code.

```
class Exploit(object):
  def __reduce__(self):
    fd = 20
    return (subprocess.Popen,
            (('/bin/sh',), # args
             0,            # bufsize
             None,         # executable
             fd, fd, fd    # std{in,out,err}
             ))
```

What does fd mean in this parameter? I would assume it has a value of 20. As far as i know `subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)` and so on. So where does the fd come from?

Link from where code is obtained

https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/03/exploiting-pickle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ook at the documentation for `subprocess.Popen`:

```
$ pydoc subprocess.Popen
```

You will find the documentation for the `__init__` method:

```
__init__(self, args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None,
stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, 
shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, 
startupinfo=None, creationflags=0)
```

Which tells you that this call:

```
subprocess.Popen,
        (('/bin/sh',), # args
         0,            # bufsize
         None,         # executable
         fd, fd, fd    # std{in,out,err}
         ))
```

Is passing in values for `args`, `bufsize`, `executable`, `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. So in this case, the code is setting stdin, stdout, and stderr to the called process to `20`, which will be interpreted as a standard Unix file descriptor and corresponding either to a file opened elsewhere in the code or to a file descriptor generated by output redirection on the part of the caller.

Comment: Hi could you shed more light on this comment "corresponding either to a file opened elsewhere in the code or to a file descriptor generated by output redirection on the part of the caller."

Comment: An open file in unix is represented in the kernel as in integer file descriptor.   If you open a file in Python (`myfile = open('something')`), you can see the corresponding file descriptor by looking at the `fileno()` method (`print myfile.fileno()`).  So a file descriptor of 20 *could* correspond to a file opened elsewhere in the code.  In the shell, you can open new file descriptors with i/o redirection such as `myscript 20>output.log`, which would redirect fd 20 to the file `output.log`.  Without seeing the rest of the code involved it's not really possdible to be more accurate.

Comment: @aceminer The linked code demonstrates an exploit. The attacker is trying to guess which file descriptor his connection is on. If he guesses right, then the newly spawned shell process is now reading from/writing to the attacker's connection and he has compromised the system. If he guesses wrong, he can change the file descriptor number and repeat the attack.

Comment: @aceminer: (In case this is causing confusion for you or whoever reads this later...)   A "descriptor" in Unix has _nothing_ to do with Python's much more recent use of the term.  In Python, "descriptor" is the protocol that allows you to invisibly replace `dotted.attribute_lookup` with the result of executing a method.  This code refers to the Unix operating system's definition, where it is an integer uniquely identifying each file a process is using.  (The file my program reads on descriptor 3 is not the same file _your_ program reads or writes on descriptor 3... except maybe by chance.)